# How to implement Qt messageClicked() signal of balloon message on Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to implement a feature on an application using c++ with Qt library. 
When this application gets a new text message, it shows some balloon message around the systemTrayIcon of this application.
When I clicked on the balloon message, Qt will send out a mesageClicked() signal, and the text message center will show up.

Everything is fine on windows, since Qt supports messageClicked() signal of balloon message on windows.
But on Mac, Qt doesn’t support this messageClicked() signal of balloon message.  So, I want to implement this signal by myself.

I know how to get mouse click and location event, but I don’t know how to figure out what area of the balloon message is, so that whenever the mouse click on the balloon message, I can know.

Can you please give me any idea about how to implement this messageClicked() signal on Mac?